# Img path inside <td> showing but can't click on it

Tags: php, html, css, image, html-table

I have a huge issue with clicking and opening an image inside my database filled table. I created a MySQL database and implemented it via PHP in a table on my site. Everything works just fine except images. They are showing up as a thumbnails on table (and they should be, because I put height very small) but when I want to click on them, nothing happens. It just don't want to go on that place where the image is located (even though the link to the image appears on the bottom of the browser and my cursor goes into "link" mode).

That part of my PHP code:

```
echo "<table class=table>                        
           <tr>  
           <th><b>ID:</b></th> 
           <th><b>Ime:</b></th>                             
           <th><b>Dimenzije-cm:</b></th> 
           <th><b>Kol.po-m2:</b></th> 
           <th><b>Te×ina-kg/m2:</b></th> 
           <th><b>Na paleti-m2:</b></th> 
           <th><b>Images:</b></th> 
           </tr>"; 
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['ime'] . "</td>";                                 
    echo "<td>" . $record['dimenzije-cm'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['kol.po-m2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['tezina-kg/m2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['na paleti-m2'] . "</td>";                               
    echo "<td><a href=\"" . $record['images'] . "\" > 
              <img src=\"" . $record['images'] . "\" height=\"30\" /></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Here are screenshots of the problem:

1. -

   [image]

   On this screenshot you can see that the `img` is active and that the link is showing on the bottom page of the browser, but when I click on it, nothing happens.
2. -

   [image]

   On the second screenshot, you can see what happens when I type the image page `src` into the browser address bar. It opens normally and clearly the image is where it is supposed to be.

The problem could also be in my bootstrap CSS, so I will upload it for you  to check it out please...

http://speedy.sh/K5UXh/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your img element style to { display: block }

Comment: Can you right click and do an Inspect Element and then print the screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, after long of research and code exploiting, I found out that the problem was in my .js files. I had few of them colide each other with same lines but different values and commands, which led to glitches and buggs in code overall. Solution was to use only one main .js file and for .js parts that you really need, post them directly into head between